# How to Manipulate history.length and set it to more than 50?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The history.length property returns the URL in the history, however we could only set it to a maximum of 50. Reference - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_his_length.asp

Is there a feature that could allow us to exceed this amount?

Comment: I can find nothing about such a limitation in the specification. I wonder where w3schools is getting that information from, it *may* be incorrect.

Comment: It isn't incorrect, you can test it out. History.length cannot be more than 50 .

Comment: Do you mean you navigated more than 50 times in the same tab but `history.length` remained stuck to `50`? Can you reproduce this on several browsers?

Comment: Yes. It could be reporduced. Just use history.pushstate and push more than 50 objects to the history. You'll see the history.length cannot be more than 50.